# jQuery Access Across Chrome Ext. Layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a particularly odd issue when developing Chrome extensions using jQuery.  I have two "frames" in my extension, the popup page and the background page.  Both of these pages have included within them the jQuery library.  Essentially what I would like to do is when the user clicks on the browser action icon a loading screen is shown while the background page gathers the data and then sends it back to the popup page.  I've tried to do this by having the popup page call a function in the background page and then have the background page use the popup window's dom to access the data and show in the UI.  However, I'm noticing that when you get a Window object back from chrome.extension.getView() it does not have access to the jQuery library for some reason.  Any call to '$' is met with a 'method not found' error.  So what would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: I won't directly answer your quesiton, but don't forget that background pages and extension pages are not run in the same context. Whatever the problem with jQuery is, the extension won't be able to read the background page anyway. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: @rds Well you can still call background methods from the popup page so the popup page has if anything limited access to the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using [message parsing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). Essentially, you add a listener function in your background page, similar to this: (slightly simplified example from the documentation page)

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
    {
        console.log("Received a request!");
        if (request.message == "hello")
            sendResponse({message: "goodbye"});
    });
```

The background page fetches the information, and returns it to the popup using the sendResponse function.

Then in your popup, you implement something like this:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({message: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.message);
});
```

Messages (the `{message: "hello"}` parts) can be any JSON compatible object.